# Why doesn't zuluCrypt let me unmount my device from the terminal when the GUI works?

Tags: linux, terminal, encryption, veracrypt

No matter what path I provide, it gives the same nonsensical error. The manual doesn't explain anything.

```
sudo zuluCrypt-cli -q /run/media/private/a/sde1
ERROR: Required option( device path ) is missing for this operation

sudo zuluCrypt-cli -q /dev/mapper/zuluCrypt-1000-NAAN-sde1-2599965352
ERROR: Required option( device path ) is missing for this operation

sudo zuluCrypt-cli -q /dev/sde1
ERROR: Required option( device path ) is missing for this operation
```

What does it want? I've given it every cryptic path related to the USB stick, as shown in zuluCrypt itself and in `df`. Nothing is apparently good enough.

If I right-click it in the zuluCrypt GUI and select "Unmount", it unmounts it without errors. But I need to do it from the terminal (automated).

PS: The only reason I don't use VeraCrypt is that Debian doesn't have it in its APT repository, and I would have to manually install and maintain it if I used it instead of zuluCrypt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The manual doesn't explain anything.

I agree the [manual](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/zulucrypt-cli/zuluCrypt-cli.1.en.html) is kinda cryptic and ambiguous. It's very different from manuals I'm used to. The information you need is in one of the examples:

> examples:
> […]
> close volume ; `zuluCrypt-cli -q -d /dev/sdc1`
> […]
>
> operation list:
> […]
> `-q` close an opened encrypted volume
> […]
>
> options that goes with above operations:
> […]
> `-d` path to a file or partition with encrypted volume

Apparently `-q` does not take any option-argument, it's `-d` what takes an option-argument like `/dev/sdc1`.

There is no `-d` in your commands, this is why they failed.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I would never have figured it out and I don't understand how you did it. I don't understand why manuals can't (almost) ever explain things clearly. `sudo 'zuluCrypt-cli' -q -d '/dev/sde1'` did the trick, but I'm unsure if this message is a bad thing: `device-mapper: remove ioctl on zuluCrypt-1000-NAAN-sde1-2599965352  failed: Device or resource busy`, which is said just before `SUCCESS: volume closed successfully`?

Comment: @Stan I have no experience with zuluCrypt whatsoever, I have never used it, I cannot help you further. I only spotted the example in the manual. Without the example I would probably interpret the manual like you did.

Comment: `failed: Device or resource busy` is usually printed if e.g. you have shell open on a device that you (attempt to) umount (i.e. you have done a `cd` to a folder on the device).